# how to resolve promise in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, promise

While running tests on the following Typescript code I got this error on Terminal: '**Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.**'.

Here it goes the requirement regarding Interface **code** method --> A method called code(), which returns a Promise that resolves to a string.

And regarding **code** method implementation --> 'Finally, the interface enforces the class to implement the code() method. The resolved string depends on the value of the name and language properties of the Developer instance'.

What have I done incorrectly?
Please, how should I resolve a promise in Typescript?

```
// TODO: Implement your developer interface and class in this file
interface DeveloperInterface {
  //Two getter methods getName(),
  //and getLanguage() that return a string
  getName() : string;
  getLanguage(): string;

  //The respective setter methods setName(name: string),
  //and setLanguage(language: string) without return value (void)
  setName(name: string) : void;
  setLanguage(language: string): void;

  //A method called code(),
  //which returns a Promise that resolves to a string
  code<T>(): Promise<T>;
}


//implementing the DeveloperInterface interface
class Developer implements DeveloperInterface{

  //constructor method
  constructor(name: string, language: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.language = language;
  }

  //private class variables
  private name = '';
  private language = '';

  //providing getName method
  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  //providing setName method
  setName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;  
  }

  //providing getLanguage method
  getLanguage() {
    return this.language;
  }

  //providing setLanguage method
  setLanguage(language: string) {
    this.language = language;
  }

  //providing code method
  async code<T>(): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve) => {
      if (this.getLanguage() === 'nodejs') {
        resolve: (`console.log("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);
      } else if (this.getLanguage() === 'java') {
        resolve: (`System.out.println("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);
      } else if (this.getLanguage() === 'python') {
        resolve: (`print("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Unsupported language: ${this.getLanguage()}`);
      }
    });
  }
}

//Create and export (default) a Class Developer
export { Developer as default };
```

Comment: ``resolve: (`console.log("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);`` is not how you call a function in JavaScript. You haven't called the `resolve` parameter.

Comment: Also, why are you using a promise? The function `code` is synchronous. It's not even a generic, since nothing in it varies types.

Comment: @VLAZ, it's mandatory to use promise according to test requirement

 ``` describe('code', () => {
    it('should resolve with node code', async () => {
      const developer = new Developer('Nicole', 'nodejs')
      const code = await developer.code()
      assert.equal(code, 'console.log("Hello, Nicole!")')
    })```

Comment: If you make an async function it automatically returns a Promise, Try `async function f() { return 1}` and then `console.assert(f() instanceof Promise)`

Comment: @BrunoFranzini `await` does not require a promise, it only permits it. You could still write a `developer.code()` method that just returns a plain value.

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out.

in the interface code method should be like this:
`code() : Promise<any>`

and in the code method implementation should be:

```
  async code() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (this.getLanguage() === 'nodejs') {
        resolve(`console.log("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);
      } else if (this.getLanguage() === 'java') {
        resolve(`System.out.println("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);
      } else if (this.getLanguage() === 'python') {
        resolve(`print("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")`);
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Unsupported language: ${this.getLanguage()}`);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new Promise using constructor. Your function is async. So you could do like this `async code() { const language = this.getLanguage(); switch(language){ case 'nodejs': return \`console.log("Hello, ${this.getName()}!")\` /* etc*/ }}` Returning from async function equivalent to resolving the promise being returned.

Comment: Now It got, what you mean in previous comment by unecessarily new Promise declaration.